# Microsoft DPM virtualisation

Tags: hyper-v, scdpm

can Microsoft DPM backup server be virtualised? Are there any special requirements?

Also, does DPM need to be in a domain or can it live without being a member of a domain?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

> Can Microsoft DPM backup server be virtualised?

Yes, it can, but there are some [limitations](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440941.aspx).

> Virtual DPM installations do not support the following:
>
> - Windows 2012 Storage Spaces.
> - Virtual hard drives built on top of storage spaces.
> - Local or remote hosting of VHDX files on Windows 2012 storage spaces.
> - Enabling Disk Dedupe on volumes hosting virtual hard drives.
> - Windows 2012 iSCSI targets (which use virtual hard drives) as a DPM storage pool.
> - NTFS compression for volumes hosting VHD files used in the DPM storage pool.
> - Bitlocker on volumes hosting VHD files used for the storage pool.
> - A native 4K sector size of physical disks for VHDX files in the DPM storage pool.
> - Virtual hard drives hosted on Windows 2008 servers.

It works fine for smaller environments, but anything over medium size would do best to use direct attach or SAN-based storage.

> does DPM need to be in a domain or can it live without being a member of a domain?

It needs to be in a domain.
[DPM 2007 reference.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb808850.aspx)
[DPM 2012 reference.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj651645.aspx)
You can however set up a small domain, only to host DPM, and install the backup agents on other domains / workstation computers.
You're only causing yourself more work this way though, it is best to join DPM to your primary domain.